# Must one wait for a Cohen, Levi or Yisra'el during public Torah reading?

Tags: torah-reading

I'm mentioning 3 scenarios that may occur during public Torah reading.

1 - The only Cohen in the shul is in the middle of the silent *Amidah*. Should you wait for him to finish, and if so, how long? Or is any waiting, even 20 seconds considered *torach tzibbur*? If you don't wait, should you call a Levi or Yisra'el?

2 - The Cohen had his aliyah, the only Levi is in the middle of *Amidah*. Should the Cohen take the Levi Aliyah or should cong. wait for the Levi?

3 - The only *Yisra'el* in shul is in the middle of *Amidah*. AFAIK, a Cohen or Levi cannot take a Yisra'el *aliyah*. But waitig for the Yisra'el to finish might be *torach tzibbur* (say he's at the beginning). Do we still have to wait for him, or is there an exception to use a Cohen or Levi to sub for him?

Comment: If there's no Cohen, a *Yisra'el* may take his place. Thus, questions 1 & 3 are essentially the same.

Comment: @Ploni Actually, 1 and 3 are NOT the same. In 1, technically, there is no Cohen, and, yes, Yisra'el can replace him. The question is if we should wait, anyway. Also, a Levi is available. Q 3 says that a Yisra'el is NOT available. Where do you see the similarity?

Comment: they're both in the middle of the the *Amidah*, rendering them temporarily unavailable. The question is must the congregation wait for them to become available.

Comment: @Ploni But it's still possible to argue that in 1 you don't have to wait for the Kohen while in 3 you have to wait for the Yisrael, because although you can have a Yisrael sub for a Kohen you can't have a Kohen sub for a Yisrael. And vice versa - in 1 you might have to wait because he is there and it's denigrating him to call up a Levi or Yisrael instead, while in 3 you might be able to move ahead because of the kavod of the tzibbur.

Comment: @DonielF Re your first point: I recall learning that in a minyan with only Kohanim they can get any aliyah. So whatever logic will apply in case one will be the same logic in case 3. Re your second point: regarding case 1 it says clearly in Shulchan Aruch that it's not a problem of denigrading him because everyone can see he's davening.

Comment: Didn't the Kohen know he was going to be called to the Torah?

Comment: @Ploni The OP never specified it was only Kohanim. I read the question as a shul with a mix of Kohanim, Leviim, and Yisraelim, and in each variation all members of one group are unavailable to be oleh. Would you mind quoting that SA?

Comment: @DonielF OC 135:5. The reason can be found in Mishnah Berurah 135:17.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### To answer question 1:

*Magen Avraham* writes that they should not wait for the *Kohen* because of *tirchah di'tzibbura* (135:6) or because of the honor of the congregation (135:7).

> If you don't wait, should you call a Levi or Yisra'el?

Kitzur Shulchan Aruch ([23:10](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0041_L5)) writes that a *Levi* or *Yisrael* may be called in his place.

#### To answer question 2:

Once again there's an issue of *tirchah di'tzibbura* if they were to wait, so it would seem that the *Kohen* should take his place.

#### To answer question 3:

As above, there's the issue of *tirchah di'tzibbura* if they were to wait, so practically it should be considered that he's not there.

Regarding a city (or a shul) which inhabited entirely by *Kohanim*, Shulchan Aruch ([135:12](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x510)) writes:

> עִיר שֶׁכֻּלָּהּ כֹּהֲנִים ... אוֹ שֶׁאֵין שָׁם יִשְׂרָאֵל כְּלָל, קוֹרֵא כֹּהֵן אַחַר כֹּהֵן, שֶׁאֵין שָׁם מִשּׁוּם פְּגָם, שֶׁהַכֹּל יוֹדְעִים שֶׁאֵין שָׁם אֶלָּא כֹּהֲנִים...‏
>
> A city which is [inhabited] entirely by *Kohanim* ... or there is no *Yisrael* there at all, they call one *Kohen* after another, because there is no issue of *pegam*, since everyone knows that there are only *Kohanim* present...

If there are both *Kohanim* and *Levi'im* present, Mishnah Berurah ([135:45](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14164&st=&pgnum=35)) writes that they should alternate between the *Kohanim* and the *Levi'im*.